# plotting type issue: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, physics

I am transcribing an astrophysics paper into python (the paper did not define `x` and `y`, so for now I've set them to zero). But I'm having trouble plotting with error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

note that if I put `plt.plot(R,Vd)` it gives error:

> ValueError: `x` and `y` must have same first dimension, but have shapes `(100,)` and `(1,)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
from scipy.special import ellipe
from scipy.special import ellipk

#constants
G = 4.300e-6    #gravitational constant (kpc/solar mass*(km/s)^2)
Edc = 8.44e2      #central value, solar_m / pc^2
Rd = 3.5     #scale radius, kpc

r = np.linspace(0,100,100)
Ed = lambda r: Edc*np.exp(-r/Rd)     #surface mass density
R = np.linspace(0,100,100)     #radius,kpc
x = 0     #radius,kpc
y = 0     #radius,kpc

s = np.sqrt((R-x)**2+y**2)   #distance between mass element and point

def f(x, y):
    return Ed(r)*(R-x)/s**3
F= lambda R:G*dblquad(f, -np.inf, np.inf, -np.inf, np.inf)
Vd = lambda R: np.sqrt(R*F(R))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9.0,8.0))                #size of the plot
ax = plt.axes()
ax.grid(True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,which='minor',linestyle='--')
plt.plot(R,Vd(R))
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer? If you have and found it useful you should consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so the question is marked as such for future users.

Answer (score 1):

The below will explain the reason for the error and how to resolve it, but I would recommend either adding more detail to the question about what you are trying to accomplish or opening a new question with the [physics](/questions/tagged/physics) and [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) tags to help you refactor the code to satisfy the requirements outlined below.

---

The error arises because the `func` argument in `scipy.integrate.dblquad` has to have the signature

```
func(y, x) -> scalar
```

Not

```
func(x, y) -> np.ndarray
```

So you can't return an array from `f(x, y)`. If you do

```py
def f(y, x):
    return (Ed(r[0]) * R[0] - x) / s[0]**3
```

You will not get that error. However, you also won't get the result you're looking for because `f(y, x)` is only being applied to a single radius and distance. In order to get the result you want you will need to refactor your code to accommodate the requirement that `f(y, x)` has a call signature wherein it returns a single float value.

There is another issue with the code, `scipy.integrate.dblquad` returns two values, the error and the resultant integral - assuming you are trying to use the resulting integral and not the error you need to do

```py
F = lambda R: G*dblquad(f, -np.inf, np.inf, -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
```